# Problems sending .m4a files from android to ios

Tags: android, ios, mediarecorder, m4a

we're having problems sending .m4a files from android to iOS.

It seems that the file is sent correctly but, when we try to reproduce the file in iOS it says that the duration is 00:00.

Here's some code from android `MediaRecorder` configuration:

```
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(16000);
mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(fileRecordingName);

try  {
    mediaRecorder.prepare();
    mediaRecorder.start();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And here's some code from iOS configuration:

```
NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
[recordSetting setValue:  [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMedium] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
```

Has anyone a clue of what is going on?
It seems that configurations are the same.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in recording (the code you've included) and not in sending the file from one device to the other?

Comment: I think that's not the problem, we encode it as base64 and send it as a String to the server, and then the server send it to the other phone. Android-android, ios-android and ios-ios are working perfectly, the only case that fails is android-ios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! It was an internal error from the xcode project, refreshing it solved the problem, thanks!